# Spring Boot 1.5.3 Creating more connection than specified in application.properties

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a project where i have dual datasource configured. On testing i have limit the no of max-active connections to five but when i checked on database, i found that application create around 25+ connections.

**Code Sample**

```
# Number of ms to wait before throwing an exception if no connection is available.
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=1000
# Maximum number of active connections that can be allocated from this pool at the same time.
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=1
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=1
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=1
spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=1
# Validate the connection before borrowing it from the pool.
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-while-idle = true
spring.datasource.tomcat.validation-query = true
spring.datasource.tomcat.time-between-eviction-runs-millis = 360000


spring.rdatasource.tomcat.max-wait=1000
# Maximum number of active connections that can be allocated from this pool at the same time.
spring.rdatasource.tomcat.max-active=1
spring.rdatasource.tomcat.max-idle=1
spring.rdatasource.tomcat.min-idle=1
spring.rdatasource.tomcat.initial-size=1
# Validate the connection before borrowing it from the pool.
spring.rdatasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true
spring.rdatasource.tomcat.test-while-idle= true
spring.rdatasource.tomcat.validation-query = true
spring.rdatasource.tomcat.time-between-eviction-runs-millis = 360000
```

above connection is working fine, but exceeding no of connection to database. User which i am using is limited to 10 connection.

when i hit request to application than i am getting 
**query wait timeout error with unable to create initial pool size.**

**I am using tomcat connection pooling**

Please provide me the solution so application will run with 10 connections limit which is set at database.

Comment: I am using tomcat connection pooling, setting already specifying, for more clarification, i have edited my question regarding the same. please someone help me, my dba not allowing more than 10 connection for the user that i am using. Hence i am not able to test.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this?

Comment: Not Yet. Still seeking answer.